# Swagger produces key behaving differently in Openapi 3

Tags: python-3.x, swagger, openapi

I'm currently converting my swagger file to openapi3 and I have an endpoint thats returning a json response and I am using produces to output it as `text/plain`. I know the produces key for responses has been replaced in openapi3 by `content: text/plain: etc..` but this is no longer converting my response. So previously if I called `response.text` after calling the endpoint I would get `"This is a test."` but now I get `'"This is a test."\n'`

Swagger 2 file:

```
  /api/logs:
    get:
      description: Retrieve logs .
      operationId: controller.get_logs
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Job logs found
            schema:
              type: string
      produces:
        - text/plain
```

Openapi 3 file:

```
  /api/logs:
    get:
      description: Retrieve logs .
      operationId: controller.get_logs
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Job logs found
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
```

Below is a snippet of the application code, we call an external API and just return the response from that call. I don't have a snippet of the Api code to share but I have added some logs to display the response content:

```
resp = job.get_output() # Api call
try:
    json_resp = resp.json()
    LOGGER.info(f"Response: {resp}")
    LOGGER.info(f"JSON: {json_resp}")
    LOGGER.info(f"Text: {repr(resp.text)}")
    LOGGER.info(f"Headers: {dict(resp.headers)}")
except Exception as error:
    return (
        {
            "message": f"Failed to get job output for job: {job_id}"
        },
        HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND,
    )

return json_resp, HTTPStatus.OK, dict(resp.headers)
```

Log output:

```
LOGGER - Response: <Response [200]>
LOGGER - JSON: This is a test.
LOGGER - Text: '"This is a test."\n'
LOGGER - Headers: {'Date': 'Tue, 28 Jul 2020 15:23:31 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '18', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

What am I doing wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Please post your server code that generates the response.

Comment: @Helen I have updated my post and included all of the application code that I have access to. Unfortunately I don't have the code from the Api